# Guard against undefined in object deconstruction with default values

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

In Javascript it is possible to deconstruct objects and supply default values to declare variables.
Below the name property of school object inside user object would be assigned to the name variable.
However this also happens for undefined variables.

```
const user = {
 id: 339,
 name: 'Fred',
 age: 42,
 education: {
  school: {
   name: undefined
  }
 }
}
const {education: {school: {name}} = {school: {name: 'Dunno'}}} = user;
console.log(name); //prints: undefined
```

Above example is from [Destructuring Nested Objects](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8)

Is there a way to guard against that inside the deconstruction so that name would print the default 'Dunno'?

Comment: `const {education: {school: {name = 'Dunno'}}} = user;`

Comment: ah yeah, `const {education: {school: {name = 'Dunno'} = {}} = {}} = user` works, but it is a different syntax. How to make it work with the syntax from question?

Comment: Either make sure you have education in your second one, or don't destruct education in the first place.  Why are you wanting to destructor twice anyway?

Comment: Ah, I just realised my question does not make much sense because it is deconstructing/defaulting the whole education object first. thx @Keith for the answer.